# Duda request Validation Laravel

Tags: laravel, validación

Cómo hago para que ignore la validación , la fila con el mismo id.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class updated_cliente_request extends FormRequest {
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return True;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'primer_nombre' =>'required | Alpha | string:20',
            'otro_nombre' =>'Alpha | string:20',
            'primer_apellido' =>'required | Alpha | string:20',
            'otro_apellido' =>'Alpha | string:20',
            'ci' =>'required | digits_between::1,8 | unique:cliente,CL_CI,'.$cliente->id,
            'telefono' =>'required | digits_between::1,11 | unique:cliente,CL_telefono,'.request()->input('id').',CL_ID',
            'direccion' =>'required',
            'correo' =>'required | email | unique:cliente,CL_correo,'.request()->input('id').',CL_ID',
            'empresa_envio' =>'required | string:50',
            'estado' =>'required | exists:estado,ES_ID',
            'ciudad' =>'required | exists:ciudad,CI_ID',
            //
        ];
    }
```

eh intentado de las 2 formas y ninguna me a agarrado alguien sabe como es el comando?

Comment: ¿Cómo tiene definida sus rutas ? ¿Está utilizando Route model binding ?

Comment: ya vi mi error estaban mal las rutas , doy de baja la pregunta?

Comment: Sí, por favor elimina la pregunta.